# SignalR - get prompted for username and password on connect

Tags: signalr, signalr.client

I've got a self-hosted SignalR server which has IntegratedWindowsAuthentication turned on.
During the negotiate phase of the connection (from Chrome) the browser throws up a username/password prompt. If I click Sign In without filling in any details then it connects me to the hub as ANONYMOUS LOGON.
How can I configure things so that my Windows identity is seamlessly passed through so the hub knows who am I and that the browser doesn't prompt me?
This is a non-Core implementation of the SignalR server.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On your Main method try this:

```cs
connection.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

Read more about this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/security/hub-authorization#windows-authentication).

Comment: As stated in the problem description, this is not a .net core application.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure this helps me either as the client is Chrome (i.e. javascript).